# Twilio Python REST API - Weird error, cant send SMS

Tags: python, twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio with Python but I just can't send SMS using the twilio.rest

My tests:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 25 2011, 08:36:25)
[GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
>>> ACCOUNT_SID = "XXXXXXXXX"
>>> AUTH_TOKEN = "YYYYYYYYYY"
>>> client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
>>> message = client.messages.create(from_="+351999804432", to="+351123456789", body="message")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/andre/workspace/some.pt/3rd_party/virtualenv_some/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/messages.py", line 112, in create
return self.create_instance(kwargs)
File "/home/andre/workspace/some.pt/3rd_party/virtualenv_some/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 328, in create_instance
data=transform_params(body))
File "/home/andre/workspace/some.pt/3rd_party/virtualenv_some/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 180, in request
resp = make_twilio_request(method, uri, auth=self.auth, **kwargs)
File "/home/andre/workspace/some.pt/3rd_party/virtualenv_some/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/base.py", line 147, in make_twilio_request
uri=resp.url, msg=message, code=code)
TwilioRestException: <unprintable TwilioRestException object>
```

Some clue on what is happening?

Best Regards,

Comment: Why don't you insert a `try` block before the `message` line and catch the exception? Surely there's a string in that exception object somewhere with helpful information.

Comment: I don't know Python, but the underscore after "from" looks suspect. However, I do see it in Twilio's docs.

Comment: Hey, Twilio employee here. Is the "from" number the actual number you're trying to send the SMS message from? It might be the Twilio number does not support SMS, when you get a phone number check that it supports SMS. Some numbers only support voice, or SMS, and not both!

Comment: Further to my previous comment: I noticed it is a Portugal number, where numbers that support both voice and SMS are in short supply, it might be exactly the issue I checked. Can I ask you to check with a US or UK number to make sure you can send them out? That way we can eliminate issues with the twilio-python library.

Comment: @TwHelloInc: `from` is a keyword in Python, `from_` is a common spelling to avoid using the keyword. That's entirely normal.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you are sending to a twilio-verified number from a valid twilio number